# How do I solve gcd(2569,856) with Euclid's extendeded algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

With this algorithm I have to modulate until r = 0

Afterwards I have to find z and t in the formula gcd(2569, 856) = 2569*z + 856*t

So here's what I've done:

gcd(2569, 856)

2569 mod 856

2569/856 = 3.0011..

2569 - (856*3) = 1

856 mod 1 = 0 (end)

1 = 2569 - 856*3  = 2569 - (?)*3

This is where I'm stuck... What do I do with 856? What should replace the '?'

Comment: Try: http://www.mathcelebrity.com/euclidalgo.php

Comment: gcd(2569.856)=1=2560-856*3

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "solve gcd(2569,856)", you have either found what you are looking for or you need only a slight restatement to reach the conclusion.  The key result is where you wrote $2569 - 3*856 = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the result you want: $1 = 2569 - 856 \cdot 3$.

Indeed, $\gcd(2569, 856) = 1$ (as Euclid's algorithm tells you), $z = 1$ and $t = -3$.

Comment: Oh, I knew that z would be 1 and t = -3, but when you confirm it, that would mean that: 2569 - (856*3) = 2569*1 - 865*(-3)?

Comment: We have $2569 - (856\cdot3) = 2569\cdot1 + 865\cdot(-3)$, yes. We have $2569 \cdot 1 = 2569$ (multiplying by $1$ does not change the value) and $865\cdot(-3) = -865\cdot3$ (multiplying by a negative number means inverting the result of multiplication by its absolute value).

Comment: Ah, thank you! Didn't thought I could do -(856*3) = 856*(-3)

Comment: @CuriousGuy1: If we were required to use positive integer coefficients on $2569$ and $856$, we could never express a common divisor smaller than either of them.